# How to get all links through HTML Link Parser in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am working with HTML Link parser in jmeter and i want to get all the links for previous and current request. Currently i am getting only 1 random link by the script by just putting (.*)in path of my request.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to let the HTML Link Parser to "loop" for a while by putting [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) wth the HTML Link Parser to be a child of a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with defined number of loops or a [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) having a custom condition on when to exit the loop. This way HTTP Request will hit the next URL each time it will be called.

See [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial) for more detailed information and example JMeter Test Plan.